# Connect external SQL Server (MSSQL) from linux in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, connection, debian

I have a Debian server to run my CodeIgniter project. I use a MySQL as my database.

Now, I need to connect with an external database. But this isn't a MySQL server, it's an SQL Server.

I tried this:

```
$db['external']['hostname'] = 'tcp:[nameserver],[port]';
$db['external']['username'] = '[username]';
$db['external']['password'] = '[password]';
$db['external']['database'] = '[dataBaseName]';
$db['external']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['external']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['external']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['external']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['external']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['external']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['external']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['external']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['external']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['external']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['external']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

And my test file is this:

```
$DB2 = $this->load->database('external', TRUE); 
$rs = $DB2->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$ret = $rs->result_array();
var_dump($ret);
```

When I execute the file test the output is:
[image]

The external company can connect correctly, so the credentials are ok.

When I use `$db['external']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv'` the output is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issues and would like to find a way to do this. I can already connect to mssql from the same machine using Adminer, so the problem is to figure out how to do it in Codeigniter.

Comment: I do not get the same errors as you, though. Apparently I can connect to the database but the queries are returning empty, as I don't get the "Unable to connect..." error. Makes me wonder.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php):

> The SQLSRV extension can be used on the following operating systems:
>
> - Windows Vista Service Pack 2 or later
> - Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or later
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows 7

Your Debian server won't be able to use `sqlsrv_` functions.

If you need to connect to SQL Server from Linux you can use [the `PDO_DBLIB` library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php). In CodeIgniter it looks like you need to [set the DSN manually](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php):

> Some database drivers (such as PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC) might require a full DSN string to be provided. If that is the case, you should use the ‘dsn’ configuration setting, as if you’re using the driver’s underlying native PHP extension

You'll have to use a [`PDO_DBLIB` DSN](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php) in your connection string, which might begin with `sybase:`, `mssql:`, or `dblib:` (depending on how PHP was compiled). It looks like Debian packages may [use the `sybase:` prefix](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.0-sybase).

Answer (score -1):

Try this $rs = $this->DB2->query("SELECT * FROM table");

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Now that you have earned 50 reputation points you can (and should) use comments to ask for clarification. The answer section should only ever be used to provide answers.